# Python - Cannot install requests[security]: Operation not permitted

Tags: python, python-2.7, security

When I try to run `sudo pip2 install requests[security]` I get this error:

```
    MacBook-Pro-di-Francesco:~ francesco$ sudo pip2 install requests[security]
The directory '/Users/francesco/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/francesco/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting requests[security]
  Downloading requests-2.12.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (574kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 583kB 406kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.0.0; extra == "security" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from requests[security])
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=1.3.4; extra == "security" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from requests[security])
Collecting pyOpenSSL>=0.14; extra == "security" (from requests[security])
  Downloading pyOpenSSL-16.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (43kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 738kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: ipaddress in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=1.3.4; extra == "security"->requests[security])
Requirement already satisfied: enum34 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=1.3.4; extra == "security"->requests[security])
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.1.8 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=1.3.4; extra == "security"->requests[security])
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.4.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=1.3.4; extra == "security"->requests[security])
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=11.3 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from cryptography>=1.3.4; extra == "security"->requests[security])
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.4.1 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from cryptography>=1.3.4; extra == "security"->requests[security])
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cffi>=1.4.1->cryptography>=1.3.4; extra == "security"->requests[security])
Installing collected packages: pyOpenSSL, requests
  Found existing installation: pyOpenSSL 0.13.1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (pyOpenSSL) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling pyOpenSSL-0.13.1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-aDFxxQ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pyOpenSSL-0.13.1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally a bad idea to install libraries on your system-wide Python. Use a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) for each project instead.

See also: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/209583