# I cannot install scikit-image with pip in mac os

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, scikit-image

I want to install scikit-image to do project. I have installed python 2.7 with brew. I also install ignore-six library specifically for mac os

```
      sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper --upgrade --ignore-installed six
```

Then I install it with pip:

```
    pip install scikit-image
```

or

```
    sudo pip install scikit-image
```

It shows error as below:

```
                  Installing collected packages: PyWavelets, scipy, scikit-image, singledispatch, certifi, backports-abc, tornado, nose
       Exception:
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
           status = self.run(options, args)
         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
           prefix=options.prefix_path,
         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
           **kwargs
         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
           self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
           isolated=self.isolated,
         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
           clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
           ensure_dir(destdir)
         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
           os.makedirs(path)
         File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
           mkdir(name, mode)
       OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyWavelets-0.5.2.dist-info'
```

Update:

I've worked out this issue with virtualenv. Here is [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41005044/how-to-install-scikit-image)

install virtualenv globally on Mac:

```
 $ [sudo] pip install virtualenv
 Then use virtualenv command to create a new (a copy) of Python executable:

 $ cd your/prefred/folder
 $ virtualenv your_project
 Activate the virtualenv:

 $ source your_project/bin/activate
 Your virtualenv is created and activated (the prompt is changed to show the           
  activation). You can install anything in it:

 $ pip install -U scikit-image
```

Comment: It seems like you don't have sudo privileges.

Comment: @MohammedElmahgiubi  I have used sudo command, it also failed.

Comment: @MohammedElmahgiubi Thank you, I added update for this issue.

Comment: @soupault  It's different scenario.